# Handsontable Sorting Integers Like Strings

Tags: jquery, json, handsontable

I have an implementation of Handsontable 0.11.2 that receives data in JSON format.  I have made the columns sortable and have one numeric column (I have defined it as numeric) that still sorts like a string.  I tried making it a float by adding .0 to the end formatting and, even though it showed the 0, it still sorts as a string.  I have seen a few potential solutions doing Google searches but have not found a solution that works.  My handsontable setup is below, any advice is much appreciated.

```
$(document).on('click','.report',function(event) {

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'pending.php',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json) {
        $('.item').remove();
        $(".welcome").hide();

        $(".carousel-inner").append("<div id='faTable'></div>");
        var $container = $("#faTable");
        var $parent = $container.parent();
        $container.handsontable({
            data: json.data,
            startRows: 10,
            startCols: 8,
            rowHeaders: true,
            manualColumnResize: true,
            manualColumnMove: true,
            columnSorting: true,
            colHeaders: ['Lot','Number','Reason','Results','Billback','Status','Rank'],
            contextMenu: true,
            colWidths: [80,150,300,200,200,50,50],
            columns: [
                {data: "lot", type: 'text',readOnly: true},
                {data: "number",type: 'text',readOnly: true},
                {data: "reason", type: 'text',readOnly: true},
                {data: "results", type: 'text',readOnly: true},
                {data: "billback", type: 'text',readOnly: true},
                {data: "status", type: 'text',readOnly: true},
                {data: "rank", type: 'numeric',readOnly: true}
            ]
        });
    },
    error: function(data) {

    }
});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an open bug logged here:
https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/883

I ended up just filtering everything that might be a number like this before I added it to the handsontable's data set:

```
var filterFloat = function (value) {
    if(/^(\-|\+)?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|Infinity)$/
      .test(value))
      return Number(value);
  return NaN;
}

// for the sake of sorting numbers vs strings:
if(filterFloat(stringNumberVar)){
   stringNumberVar = filterFloat(stringNumberVar);
}
```

It seems like something that should get fixed or that you could add to a fork fairly easily because they have a date sort that's also a bit fickle.

I'll come back and tell you about it if I decide to take on that task.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this problem in 0.15.0-beta2 while using PHP 5.5 to query MySQL and convert to JSON string. I found the data for that column also needed to be cast to a number as all data from a MySQL query is returned as a string. Out of 30 columns, four needed to be cast so I wrote this loop for the SQL results:

```
$res = Zend_Registry::get('db')->fetchAll('
    SELECT *
    FROM table
');

foreach($res as &$s) {
    $s['table_pk'] = (int) $s['table_pk'];
    $s['position'] = ($s['position']!=0 ? (int) $s['position'] : null);
    $s['height'] = ($s['height']!=0 ? (int) $s['height'] : null);
    $s['count'] = ($s['count']!=0 ? (int) $s['count'] : null);
}
```

The 'null' displays as an empty string and sorts at the bottom like other empty strings.